# Object Change Notification in Google Cloud Storage not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I did a demo from tutorial https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Application_Example. I also enabled the Google Cloud Storage JSON API in cloud console. But I got the result following:

```
$ gsutil chacl -u math-box20@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:FC gs://test-mathbox

No changes to gs://test-mathbox/
```

```
$ gsutil notifyconfig watchbucket https://math-box20.appspot.com/ gs://test-mathbox

Watching bucket gs://test-mathbox/ with application URL https://math-box20.appspot.com/ ...
Failure: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/test-mathbox/o/watch?alt=json returned "Access Not Configured">.
```

In that, math-box20 is the id of my GAE application and test-mathbox is a bucket in Google Cloud Storage. Can you help me know why that?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this error is not enabling access to the JSON API.

Could you follow [the instructions here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/#Preview) and make sure that the JSON API is enabled in your project console?

Comment: @tutorvn You shouldn't be getting that error if the JSON API is turned on. Please email gs-team@google.com with your project number and output from `gsutil -DD notifyconfig watchbucket ...`

Comment: I send the problem to gs-team. Anyway, thanks you so much. You're very kind.

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks to Google Storage Team. The problem is the credential type. More information is [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CredentialTypesSupportingVariousUseCases).

Comment: Hi Tutorvn, can u explain how you solved it. 
I have an Bucket in ProjectA, 
I have Given ProjectB FULL_CONTROL to the bucket in ProjectA, which configured properly, 
I have added a domain.com in ProjectB whitelisted domains, and it is verified too, 
I have created a Service Account in ProjectB and set it as active account in gcloud sdk from terminal

then when i try to watchbucket, i get same error as what you received